# Perl / Moose - How can I dynamically choose a specific implementation of a method?

Tags: perl, moose

I've written a simple [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) based class called `Document`. This class has two attributes: `name` and `homepage`.

The class also needs to provide a method called `do_something()` which retrieves and returns text from different sources (like a website or different databases) based on the `homepage` attribute.

Since there will be a lot of totally different implementations for `do_something()`, I'd like to have them in different packages/classes and each of these classes should know if it is responsible for the `homepage` attribute or if it isn't.

My approach so far involves two roles:

```perl
package Role::Fetcher;
use Moose::Role;
requires 'do_something';
has url => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str'
);

package Role::Implementation;
use Moose::Role;
with 'Role::Fetcher';
requires 'responsible';
```

A class called `Document::Fetcher` which provides a default implmenentation for `do_something()` and commonly used methods (like a HTTP GET request):

```perl
package Document::Fetcher;
use Moose;
use LWP::UserAgent;
with 'Role::Fetcher';

has ua => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Object',
    required => 1,
    default => sub { LWP::UserAgent->new }
);

sub do_something {'called from default implementation'}
sub get {
    my $r = shift->ua->get(shift);
    return $r->content if $r->is_success;
    # ...
}
```

And specific implementations which determine their responsibility via a method called `responsible()`:

```perl
package Document::Fetcher::ImplA;
use Moose;
extends 'Document::Fetcher';
with 'Role::Implementation';

sub do_something {'called from implementation A'}
sub responsible { return 1 if shift->url =~ m#foo#; }

package Document::Fetcher::ImplB;
use Moose;
extends 'Document::Fetcher';
with 'Role::Implementation';

sub do_something {'called from implementation B'}
sub responsible { return 1 if shift->url =~ m#bar#; }
```

My `Document` class looks like this:

```perl
package Document;
use Moose;

has [qw/name homepage/] => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str'
);

has fetcher => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Document::Fetcher',
    required => 1,
    lazy => 1,
    builder => '_build_fetcher',
    handles => [qw/do_something/]
);

sub _build_fetcher {
    my $self = shift;
    my @implementations = qw/ImplA ImplB/;

    foreach my $i (@implementations) {
        my $fetcher = "Document::Fetcher::$i"->new(url => $self->homepage);
        return $fetcher if $fetcher->responsible();
    }

    return Document::Fetcher->new(url => $self->homepage);
}
```

Right now this works as it should. If I call the following code:

```perl
foreach my $i (qw/foo bar baz/) {
    my $doc = Document->new(name => $i, homepage => "http://$i.tld/");
    say $doc->name . ": " . $doc->do_something;
}
```

I get the expected output:

```perl
foo: called from implementation A
bar: called from implementation B
baz: called from default implementation
```

But there are at least two issues with this code:

1. I need to keep a list of all known implementations in `_build_fetcher`. I'd prefer a way where the code would automatically  choose from every loaded module/class beneath the namespace `Document::Fetcher::`. Or maybe there's a better way to "register" these kind of plugins?
2. At the moment the whole code looks a bit too bloated. I am sure people have written this kind of plugin system before. Isn't there something in [MooseX](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aMooseX) which provides the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29), specifically an [Abstract Factory](http://perldesignpatterns.com/?AbstractFactory).  The constructor for your Factory class would determine which implementation to return based on its arguments.

```
# Returns Document::Fetcher::ImplA or Document::Fetcher::ImplB or ...
my $fetcher = Document::Fetcher::Factory->new( url => $url );
```

The logic in `_build_fetcher` would go into `Document::Fetcher::Factory->new`.  This separates the Fetchers from your Documents.  Instead of Document knowing how to figure out which Fetcher implementation it needs, Fetchers can do that themselves.

Your basic pattern of having the Fetcher role able to inform the Factory if its able to deal with it is good if your priority is to allow people to add new Fetchers without having to alter the Factory.  On the down side, the Fetcher::Factory cannot know that multiple Fetchers might be valid for a given URL and that one might be better than the other.

To avoid having a big list of Fetcher implementations hard coded in your Fetcher::Factory, have each Fetcher role register itself with the Fetcher::Factory when its loaded.

```
my %Registered_Classes;

sub register_class {
    my $class = shift;
    my $registeree = shift;

    $Registered_Classes{$registeree}++;

    return;
}

sub registered_classes {
    return \%Registered_Classes;
}
```

You can have something, probably Document, pre-load a bunch of common Fetchers if you want your cake and eat it too.

Comment: I haven't even thought about principles like GRASP. Somehow the way I did it seemed to be "a good way" with Moose. Now that you've mentioned them it makes of course perfect sense to use an abstract factory. I'm still not sure how to register each role. Wouldn't this require some kind of Singleton class? Right now I'm using a somewhat hacky solution: examining `%Document::Fetcher::`.

Comment: @SebastianStumpf You don't have to make things complicated just because the Moose folks have a philosophical grudge against class data, nor do you have to reach for global variables.  Normal encapsulation still works.

Comment: I solved this in the end a bit more "Mooseish" by adding a trait to the factorie's meta class which holds an `ArrayRef[Str]` attribute called `fetchers`. So I can just call `__PACKAGE__->meta->fetchers->add`. :-)